# Git rebase upon a branch that has commits combined by another rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I am working on two features simultaneously, "feature1" being the basis for "feature2". I create two branches for them; when I work on feature1, I commit into "feature1" branch; when I work on feature2, I commit into "feature2" branch, and regularly rebase "feature2" on top of "feature1":

```
git checkout feature2
git rebase feature1
... work ...
git commit ...
```

So, at some moment, I have this structure:

```
feature1: A -> B -> C
feature2: A -> B -> C -> P -> Q -> R
```

At this point, I am done with feature1; I want to squash A, B and C into a single commit D , and rebase feature2 upon this new state of feature1:

```
feature1: D
feature2: D -> P' -> Q' -> R'
```

Simple-mindedy, I run interactive rebase on feature1, successfully squash A, B and C into D, and try to rebase feature2

```
git checkout feature2
git rebase feature1
```

Now, git pulls D into the feature2 branch and tries to reapply A, B, C, P, Q and R on top of it. Of course, the updates in A, B and C are already applied by D, so they result in merge conflicts.

I figured by trial and error that when a merge conflict is reported while A, B and C are being re-applied, I just need to run

```
git rebase --skip
```

and I end up with exactly the result I need. But, first, this is not obvious if you didn't already know, and second, makes it easy to overlook and skip a potential genuine merge conflict. The latter should be unlikely, but if it happens, it's rather bad because you lose the corresponding update for good.

So, my question is: is there a better way to rebase your branch upon a branch in which some commits where recently squashed into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using the --onto option to rebase and the @n reflog commit naming to solve my problem here, which often arises when interacting with non-git VCSes, or pretty much any time you are several local branches that are interdependent but not published.

After your first rebase: (you are squashing commits, but it can be pretty much any rebase)

```
git rebase -i master feature1
```

Follow it up with a second rebase:

```
git rebase --onto feature1 feature1@1 feature2
```

OR ("long hand")

```
git checkout feature2
git rebase --onto feature1 feature1@1
```

Which says, take the commits in feature2 that aren't in the previous version of feature1 and replay them on top of the current version of feature1.

Comment: This seems a "cleaner" way than that from the previous answer, but needs some effort to get it sink down..

Answer (score 2):

Since rebasing messes with git's idea of merge history, git cannot tell automatically what you're trying to do. Instead of dealing with the conflicts and issuing a `rebase --skip` for each unwanted commit, use `git rebase -i feature1` as your final rebase command, and simply remove the unsquashed commits from the list.

Comment: The advice from @Boyd achieves the same result, with less chance to mess things up while editing the commit list, therefore I like it better. But thanks, I now understand yet another thing about git!